# NodeJS + Passport - Different Logins

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have two different "users" (more like tables, because these two groups are completely separate things): `users` and `units`. At the same time, both can be logged in. But different pages have different restrictions.

It's easy to manage one authentication type, as discussed in this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authenticating-nodejs-applications-with-passport--cms-21619). But how do I go about allowing two different types?

I'm basically concerted with `req.isAuthenticated()` being always `true` when either type is logged, which is obviously not what I want.

Thanks,